# What is best way to draw chart with large amounts of data?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf, charts

What is best way to draw chart on silverlight application ?

I see 2 ways:

- draw chart on server side and display
  on client
- fetch chart data from server and render chart on client

Both ways are "good for me".. But I see some inconvenience:

- in first case if I need to change
  e.g. chart period I need call server
  for new chart picture
- in second case I need load mass of
  data from server and store on client.. so in this case I get mobility on client..

What is best way to draw charts with **large amounts of data**? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your use-case and what the user should do with the data.
Client-side rendering gives you more flexibility with display options, ofcourse.

But you don't need to move massive amounts of data. I bet the user has much less pixels in his chart than there are data points, so you can run some aggregation functions server side before transferring data to the locally rendered chart.

Comment: _... run some aggregation functions server side before transferring data to the locally rendered chart._ Yes, I also considered that way.. For now it is best for me.. thx !

Answer (score 0):

If, you have options (DropDown lists, Check boxes, ..etc) which change the chart graph area up on user preferences or filters, Go with the 2nd option.

Use Silverlight <--> WCF <--> DB Server, this is very efficient even with large amounts of data.

On the other hand, if your chart is static (one-fits-all), prepare it on the server and you can send it to the client as an image for example.